# prefix for product attribute valu

Tags: php, product-attribute

i have this code in an observer.php :

```
<?php

class Moh3n_Attvaluecopier_Model_Observer
{

public function  copyAttribute($observer){

    if(!$this->_processFlag):

        $this->_processFlag=true;
        $_product = $observer->getProduct();
        $_productid = $_product->getId();
        $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $loadCurrentProduct = $productModel->load($_productid);
        $loadCurrentProduct->setGeneralWeight(intval($loadCurrentProduct->getWeight()));
        $loadCurrentProduct->save();
        endif;}
    }
```

it copies the `weight` attribute value into `general_weight` attribute without decimals.

i want to add a value like (KG) to `general_weight` right after copied value.
i want general_weight to show this way: `1000 KG`

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are saving it as a string, just do this:

```
$weight = intval($loadCurrentProduct->getWeight());
$gw = (string)$weight. " KG";
$loadCurrentProduct->setGeneralWeight($gw);
```

If you need to save it as an integer for comparison or something, you could add the KG when outputting the value in the template, or write a custom getter for general_weight in your model that gives you

```
return $value . " KG";
```